# New ASP.NET Core MVC Project: "Empty" or "Web Application (MVC)"?

Tags: .net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I need to create a new web application. The team has decided to use ASP.NET Core MVC (we all have experience with ASP.NET Framework MVC).

When going through the process of creating the new application, as per usual, I can choose to create an "Empty" project, or use a template like the "Web Application (Model-View-Controller)" application template.

[image]

I have always preferred using the Empty templates because:

- I manually choose each dependency in application
- I don't have to carefully delete things that I don't want included

However, I am wondering if the intention of these templates is to use them as a base template for *new production applications*.

This is my question:

1. Is the intention that new *real* applications that fall neatly into the "Web Application (Model-View-Controller)" category use that specific template (even though it includes extra sample files that will clearly need to be deleted)?
2. OR is the intention that new *real* applications start with a blank application and only include the dependencies you actually need, while the templates are more for learning/experimenting?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Answer:** It would be better to use the MVC one since the project structure in the new ASP.NET Core is easy and clear and there are no longer complex configuration files or settings implicitly handled by Visual Studio. Everything (except the project files) in the MVC template is configured with C# code in a form of [Fluent API](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fluent_interface). The initial contents in the MVC template are just a demo for how it work with the fresh new ASP.NET Core which can be very useful for ASP.NET developers to learn the whole structure and pipeline things of a simple ASP.NET Core application. And you can remove everything easily and completely whenever you want.

By the way, "ASP.NET Framework MVC" does not exist for the old one that works with .NET Framework is named "ASP.NET MVC", and the new one called "ASP.NET Core" does not target .NET Core but .NET Standard, which means it works with both .NET Framework and .NET Core.

Additionally, It would be a better practice to use VSCode and .NET Core SDK with its command line tools than to use Visual Studio. It is light, portable, fully featured, and works more natively with portable things like batch scripts for automatic building, publishing and deploying on Linux.